# Regular expression substitution. What to replace with ([^|]+$)

Tags: regex

This `([^|]+$)` extracts the last string after slash"|". What the substitution should I use to extract the specific item?

Here is my example:

https://regex101.com/r/kG5pN6/7

I tried $1 but it output the full text. What replacement value should I put in the Substitution field to get `Test`

Comment: "|" isn't a slash. regex101 is not C# and PCRE uses different substitition characters. Consider this: https://regex101.com/r/kG5pN6/8

Comment: Just use [`s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf('|')+1)`](https://ideone.com/E426RQ).

Comment: In the future, please paste your code as text into your question. A fiddle is a great addition, but the code should be visible right on the page, and hosted right on this site.

Comment: What language/environment do you want to do this in?

Comment: @NetMage Just want to see if I can do this in pure regular expression. Thanks

Comment: There is no such thing. Every regular expression language is implemented by an environment or program, and there are many different varieties. Back references in substitutions is a large area of difference.

Answer (score 0):

Using a positive lookbehind should make this considerably more efficient.

In C#,

```
var ans = Regex.Replace(str, @"(?<=\|)([^|]+)$", @"{$1}");
```

Answer (score 0):

The slash is a special character in regular expression, you need to escape special characters to use them as normal characters.
To extract any trailing character after the last occurrence of a slash in a string you could use the following regular expression:

```
\|+([^|]+$)
```

Your example in javascript would be:

```
"https://mediatemple.net||Test".match(/\|*([^|]+$)/)
// Array [ "||Test", "Test" ]
```

However such an easy task does not require the use of a regular expression which is overkilling and can affect the performance of your application.
Using a normal string manipulation is enough for your needs:

```
var s = "https://mediatemple.net||Test",
    i = s.lastIndexOf("|"),
    m = i !== -1 ? s.substr(i+1) : null;
console.log(m); // Test
```

Comment: No need (actually, shouldn't) to escape the bar in bracket expression.